# Polygon to line with ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr

I need to make vector tiles but want the source to be like my data is.made up of polygons
Can GDAL ogr2ogr convert from polygon to line?

Comment: Do you have only polygons with one outer ring or perhaps also polygons with holes or multipolygons? In the latter case, what would be the result?

Comment: anyone know how to do this with GeoPandas

Answer (score 4):

An old question but...
using ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr output.shp input.shp -dialect sqlite -f "ESRI Shapefile" -sql "select ST_ExteriorRing(geometry) as geometry from input"
```

This works for single part polygons, no holes :)

Comment: your example does not work but if I add -dialect sqlite  then yes it does work. Thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

According to one of the GDAL/OGR authors, there is no direct way of doing this using GDAL utilities, and it must be done manually (ie, using either a GIS, or using scripts/code, eg, with GDAL/OGR API).  See details and reasons in his full explanation here:  https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2009-September/021967.html

To do this manually, you would have to extract the polygon geometry, then from this geometry, extract the external ring geometry (remember a polygon may have multiple rings for internal holes, etc).  From this external ring geometry, you would then get a sequence of coordinates.

You would then have to construct a line geometry based on these coordinates, add it to a line feature, and then (optionally) add in all of the attributes from the original polygon (assuming the line feature class had the right attributes configured when it was created).